# Error main.cpp:194:1: error: expected ‘while’ before ‘}’ token } ayuda

Tags: c++

Les cuento el programa debe preguntar si es alumno o profesor, si es profesor debe colocar una contraseña,si es alumno debe colocar nombre,apellido y rut, los 2 al ser verificados deben responder el test de 10 preguntas con 4 alternativas, no se casi nada de c++ pero es un trabajo para la universidad, eh logrado avanzar un poco gracias a youtube y unos pequeños conocimientos, el error es el que sale en el titulo,(las preguntas se repiten, lo importante es que sirva el código). el error puede ser muy basico o puedo tener todo malo, perdon por la ignorancia

```
#include <iostream>
    #include <conio.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <math.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <cstdlib>
    #define clavetrue 1234
    #define respuesta profesor
    using namespace std;
    int opcion,nombre,apellido,rut,claveacceso,profesor,datoingresado,profe,s1,s2,z1,z2,p1,p2,p3,p4,p5,p6,p7,p8,p9,p10,n1,n2,n3,n4,n5,n6,n7,n8,n9,n10,resultado;

    int main (void)
    {
        do
        {
            printf("\nSi usted es alumno Ingrese opcion 1.\nSi usted es profesor Ingrese opcion 2\nIngrese la opcion : ");
            scanf("%d",&opcion);
            switch(opcion){
            case 1:
            printf("Si usted alumno\n");
            printf("\nIntroduzca su nombre: \napellido:\nrut:\n ingrese los datos por favor:");
            scanf("%d",&nombre);
            scanf("%d",&apellido);
            scanf("%d",&rut);
            break;
            case 2:
            printf("si usted es profesor\n ");
            cout<<"ingrese la clave de acceso: ";
            cin>>claveacceso;
            if(claveacceso!=clavetrue);
            }
            while(claveacceso!=clavetrue);
            cout<<"\n\n acesso concedido.\n";
            getch();

        printf("esta es tu evaluación cuenta con 10 preguntas de selección multiple \n");
        printf("pregunta1 \n");
        printf("¿Cuantos ojos tiene un perro? \n");
        printf("1) 2 ojos \n");
        printf("2) 9 ojos \n");
        printf("3) 2 ojos \n");
        printf("4) 7 ojo \n");
        printf("Indica tu respuesta \n");
        scanf("%i",&p1);
        if(p1==1){
        n1=1;
        }
        else{
            n1=0;
        }
        printf("cuantas patas tiene un perro \n");
        printf("1) 3 patas \n");
        printf("2) 7 patas \n");
        printf("3) 4 patas \n");
        printf("4) 9 patas \n");
        printf("Indica tu respuesta \n");
        scanf("%i",&p2);
        if(p2==3){
        n2=1;
        }
        else{
            n2= 0;
        }

        printf("cuantas patas tiene un perro \n");
        printf("1) 3 patas \n");
        printf("2) 7 patas \n");
        printf("3) 4 patas \n");
        printf("4) 9 patas \n");
        printf("Indica tu respuesta \n");
        scanf("%i",&p3);
        if(p3==1){
        n3=1;
        }
        else{
            n3= 0;
        }

        printf("cuantas patas tiene un perro \n");
        printf("1) 3 patas \n");
        printf("2) 7 patas \n");
        printf("3) 4 patas \n");
        printf("4) 9 patas \n");
        printf("Indica tu respuesta \n");
        scanf("%i",&p4);
        if(p4==3){
        n4=1;
        }
        else{
            n4= 0;
        }

        printf("cuantas patas tiene un perro \n");
        printf("1) 3 patas \n");
        printf("2) 7 patas \n");
        printf("3) 4 patas \n");
        printf("4) 9 patas \n");
        printf("Indica tu respuesta \n");
        scanf("%i",&p5);
        if(p5==3){
        n5=1;
        }
        else{
            n5= 0;
        }

        printf("cuantas patas tiene un perro \n");
        printf("1) 3 patas \n");
        printf("2) 7 patas \n");
        printf("3) 4 patas \n");
        printf("4) 9 patas \n");
        printf("Indica tu respuesta \n");
        scanf("%i",&p6);
        if(p6==3){
        n6=1;
        }
        else{
            n6= 0;
        }

        printf("cuantas patas tiene un perro \n");
        printf("1) 3 patas \n");
        printf("2) 7 patas \n");
        printf("3) 4 patas \n");
        printf("4) 9 patas \n");
        printf("Indica tu respuesta \n");
        scanf("%i",&p7);
        if(p7==3){
        n7=1;
        }
        else{
            n7= 0;
        }

        printf("cuantas patas tiene un perro \n");
        printf("1) 3 patas \n");
        printf("2) 7 patas \n");
        printf("3) 4 patas \n");
        printf("4) 9 patas \n");
        printf("Indica tu respuesta \n");
        scanf("%i",&p7);
        if(p7==3){
        n7=1;
        }
        else{
            n7= 0;
        }

        printf("cuantas patas tiene un perro \n");
        printf("1) 3 patas \n");
        printf("2) 7 patas \n");
        printf("3) 4 patas \n");
        printf("4) 9 patas \n");
        printf("Indica tu respuesta \n");
        scanf("%i",&p8);
        if(p8==3){
        n8=1;
        }
        else{
            n8= 0;
        }

        printf("cuantas patas tiene un perro \n");
        printf("1) 3 patas \n");
        printf("2) 7 patas \n");
        printf("3) 4 patas \n");
        printf("4) 9 patas \n");
        printf("Indica tu respuesta \n");
        scanf("%i",&p9);
        if(p9==3){
        n9=1;
        }
        else{
            n9= 0;
        }

        printf("cuantas patas tiene un perro \n");
        printf("1) 3 patas \n");
        printf("2) 7 patas \n");
        printf("3) 4 patas \n");
        printf("4) 9 patas \n");
        printf("Indica tu respuesta \n");
        scanf("%i",&p10);
        if(p10==3){
        n10=1;
        }
        else{
            n10= 0;
        }
        resultado=n1+n2+n3+n4+n5+n6+n7+n8+n9+n10;
        printf("tu resultado del examen es de %i",resultado);

        }   
    }
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es el objetivo de usar `do {` al comienzo de tu método main? El error dice básicamente que ahí dices que vas a usar un do-while (es la única estructura que comienza con `do {`) pero nunca pusiste `} while (alguna condición de ejecución)`.

Comment: Añado y corrijo: sí lo haces pero te vuelas el cierre del switch-case que tienes a continuación. Entonces, la compilación lo entiende como el cierre de la estructura interior (el switch) y entiende que alguna llave de cierre más adelante es la del do-while y te pide que se lo pongas.

Comment: @Alfabravo muchas gracias me costo entender, ya que soy casi un ignorante en el tema pero logro funcionar

Answer (score 1):

Te falta una llave después del `switch` para emparejarla con la apertura del `do`:

```
do {
    printf("\nSi usted es alumno Ingrese opcion 1.\nSi usted es profesor Ingrese opcion 2\nIngrese la opcion : ");
    scanf("%d", &opcion);
    switch (opcion) {
    case 1:
        printf("Si usted alumno\n");
        printf("\nIntroduzca su nombre: \napellido:\nrut:\n ingrese los datos por favor:");
        scanf("%d", &nombre);
        scanf("%d", &apellido);
        scanf("%d", &rut);
        break;
    case 2:
        printf("si usted es profesor\n ");
        cout << "ingrese la clave de acceso: ";
        cin >> claveacceso;
        if (claveacceso != clavetrue)
            ;
    } // <--- Cierra el switch
}     // <--- Cierra el do-while
while (claveacceso != clavetrue)
```

Consecuentemente te sobra una llave al final de `main`:

```
    resultado = n1 + n2 + n3 + n4 + n5 + n6 + n7 + n8 + n9 + n10;
    printf("tu resultado del examen es de %i", resultado);
// } <---- Esta llave sobra
return 0; // <---- El return te falta.
```